# Finding the equations of the planes that describe a cube, given by two planes and a sphere it contains

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a question that requires me to find the equations of 4 planes that describe a cube given two other planes, and a sphere it contains. I've figured out that the two given planes are perpendicular, and that the radius of the sphere is 1 unit. So 2 of the other planes would have to be parallel to the given ones, just 2 units away. I'm not so sure how to find the equations of those planes though.

Any suggestions?

[image: Question]

Comment: then planes to find are 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS

if a plane of the cube is tangent in P with normal n then there exists another plane in -P with tangent n

you already have 2 normal vectors, you could find the third you need by cross product

Comment: I found the third normal vector to be <-3,3,0>, but I'm not too sure what you mean by the first part. What is P?

Comment: That’s a correct third normal vector, you can simplify it as (1,-1,0). P is a point at which the plane is tangent to the sphere.

Comment: So if I find P, then I can say that x-y=n dot P would be one of the equations?

Comment: take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539188/find-the-shortest-distance-between-line-and-plane-in-this-cuboid/2539199#2539199

Comment: e.g. you know that a tangent plane passes for the point $P(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$ with normal $n(1,1,1)$ thus fir symmetry you know that there exists another plane in $Q=-P(-1/\sqrt{3},-1/\sqrt{3},-1/\sqrt{3})$ that share the same normal $n$.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes total sense now. And I also noticed the formula distance = |d|/||n||, so for the planes with normal <1,-1,0>, I can say that the distance to the origin is 1 since the plane is touching the sphere which has a radius of 1.Then I have 1*||n||=d, so one of the other planes is x-y=√2 

Am I correct on all of this?